# XPath not generating array for single element arrays

Tags: arrays, json, xpath, pipeline

So I am writing a Pipeline Pilot Script.

I want to create json objects from my records by creating property names equal to xpath of my required structure and then unflattening them.

I have 2 data records:

```
Name: Sunday
Group: ["Sun","Day"]

Name: Monday
Group1: ["Mon"]
```

Now what Im doing is:

```
name : Sunday
groups[1]/@id : "Sun"
groups[2]/@id : "Day"

name: Monday
groups[1]/@id : "Mon"
```

What Im expecting:

```
[{
    "name" : "Sunday",
    "groups" : [
         {"id":"Sun"},{"id":"Day"}
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Monday",
    "groups" : [
         {"id":"Mon"}
    ]
}]
```

What Im getting:

```
[{
    "name" : "Sunday",
    "groups" : [
         {"id":"Sun"},{"id":"Day"}
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Monday",
    "groups" : {"id":"Mon"}   <--- Why??
}]
```

In case anyone is familiar with Pipeline Pilot, Im using the Unflatten Hierarchy component to do the unflattening after I create the property names as per the XPath, and this is what I get.